# MongoDb Query on inner array

Tags: mongodb

I have a following document structure

```
Users:[{
    "name": "test",
    "leaveBalance": 20,
    "leaveHistory": [
       {
          type: "Leave",
          numberofDays:2,
          status:"Approved"
       },
       {
          type: "WFH",
          numberOfDays:1,
          status: "Approved"
       },
       {
           type: "Leave",
           numberOfDays:2,
           status: "Cancelled"
       }
     ]
}, 
{
 ...
}
]
```

I need a query to find the total number of days a person took leave from this collection. number of days of leave is considered only if status is Approved and leave type is "Leave". Is there a way in mongodb to query and find the number ?

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
Users.aggregate([
{
    $match:{
        _id:user_id,
        "leaveHistory.type ":"Leave",
        "leaveHistory.status": "Approved"
    }
}, 
{
    unwind:"leaveHistory"
}, 
{
    $project:{
         $count: "numberofDays"
    }   
}
], (err, results)=>{
    console.log(err, results);
})
```

Comment: Is this in mongo query syntax ?

Comment: yes, mongo have aggregation query framework , that have more methods read more https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/aggregation/

Comment: The query doesnt seem to work for me. It returns as many values as present in the leaveHistory instead of sum of numberofDays per user.